# Указатели и ссылки на произвольные типы

Tags: c++

Расшифруйте, желательно объясните на примере...

В общем случае указатель на обьект одного типа не может указывать на обьект другого типа... В C++ указатель-ссылка на базовый класс может указывать-ссылаться на обьект производного класса-типа...

Приведите пример кода... Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base
{};

main()
{
  Base* base = new Derived(); // указатель на базовый класс фактически ссылается на объект производного класса.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все моя невнимательность.

Answer (score 2):

> В общем случае указатель на обьект одного типа не может указывать на обьект другого типа... В C++ указатель-ссылка на базовый класс может указывать-ссылаться на обьект производного класса-типа...

Ещё указатель типа void* может ссылаться на любой объект.